# get value of columns in previous row and add to the next columns of the next row

Tags: mysql, database, count, sum

I will create a graph of population by gender every year, and the graph looks like the image below. [image]

But I'm having a hard time with the query.

**Query**

```
  SELECT
       year_added,
       COUNT(case when gender='Male' then 1 end) as malecount,
       COUNT(case when gender='Female' then 1 end) as femalecount,
       COUNT(*) as totalcount
  FROM tbl
  WHERE status = 1
  GROUP BY year_added
```

**Result**

[image]

In the result, 2016 male count is 4 and female count is 8. In 2017, I want the male count of 2016 to be added on the male count on 2017, meaning 2017 male count will be 5, same with female count and total count. I provided an image below of what the result should look like. Can you help me how to do this for me to proceed on doing the graph? Or is there any other way to achieve this?

[image]

Comment: These individuals are presumably immortal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    year_added,
    @malecount_v := @malecount_v + malecount as malecount,
    @femalecount_v := @femalecount_v + femalecount as femalecount,
    @totalcount_v := @totalcount_v + totalcount as totalcount
FROM (
    SELECT
       year_added,
       COUNT(case when gender='Male' then 1 end) as malecount,
       COUNT(case when gender='Female' then 1 end) as femalecount,
       COUNT(*) as totalcount
    FROM tbl
    WHERE status = 1
    GROUP BY year_added
    ORDER BY year_added
) t1
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @malecount_v := 0, @femalecount_v := 0, @totalcount_v := 0) t2
```

Comment: @Strawberry So what is your suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

In Mysql you can do it with [variables](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/user-variables.html), like:

```
SELECT
     year_added,
     (@iMalecount := (COUNT(CASE WHEN gender = 'Male' THEN 1 END) + @iMalecount)) AS malecount,
     (@iFemalecount := (COUNT(CASE WHEN gender = 'Female' THEN 1 END) + @iFemalecount)) AS femalecount,
     (@iTotalcount := (COUNT(gender) + @iTotalcount)) AS totalcount
FROM tbl
WHERE status = 1
GROUP BY year_added
```

but is not 100% fiable as you can read in the documentation.

In other SQL flavour probably you need a stored procedure.

Answer (score -1):

you can simply use

```
 WITH TableCount AS 
(
     SELECT
       year_added,
       COUNT(case when gender='Male' then 1 end) as malecount,
       COUNT(case when gender='Female' then 1 end) as femalecount,
       COUNT(*) as totalcount
  FROM tbl
  WHERE status = 1
  GROUP BY year_added
)
```

And after that use following query

```
    SELECT 
       SUM(malecount) as 'malecount',
       SUM(femalecount) as 'femalecount',
       SUM(totalcount) as 'totalcount'
    FROM TableCount
```

If you are using `MySql` you can use temporary table to do something like CTE

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS TableCount AS (
SELECT
           year_added,
           COUNT(case when gender='Male' then 1 end) as malecount,
           COUNT(case when gender='Female' then 1 end) as femalecount,
           COUNT(*) as totalcount
      FROM tbl
      WHERE status = 1
      GROUP BY year_added
)
```

And then you can use above query

```
 SELECT 
       SUM(malecount) as 'malecount',
       SUM(femalecount) as 'femalecount',
       SUM(totalcount) as 'totalcount'
    FROM TableCount
```

> You can use the TEMPORARY keyword when creating a table. A TEMPORARY
>   table is visible only to the current session, and is dropped
>   automatically when the session is closed. This means that two
>   different sessions can use the same temporary table name without
>   conflicting with each other or with an existing non-TEMPORARY table of
>   the same name. (The existing table is hidden until the temporary table
>   is dropped.) To create temporary tables, you must have the CREATE
>   TEMPORARY TABLES privilege.

*By using temporary table concept you can achieve common table expression kind of functionality in MySql*

Comment: I think he wants a running total.

Comment: I don't think that MySQL supports common table expressions.

Comment: yes MySql was not mention in the question when I was writing the answer, Edited my answer accordingly @TimBiegeleisen